# Counting the number of ordered possibly nonconsecutive substrings that form consecutive substrings of a string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say S(N) is the length N string "012012012..." where "012" is repeated until we have N characters.

For any given N, count the number of ways of forming consecutive substrings by choosing possibly non-consecutive letters from the string in order.

E.g., for N = 5, we have S(N) = "01201"

Consecutive substrings and counts:

```
'0', 2
'1', 2
'2', 1
'01', 3 (the two consecutive '01' along with the first and last character of '01201').
'12', 1
'20', 1
'012', 1
'120', 1
'201', 1
'0120', 1
'1201', 1
'01201', 1

Total: 16
```

How can we calculate this efficiently for arbitrary N? I will post my best answer as a solution.

Note This question is originally from Cococino223, but it was poorly worded and was deleted before it could be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say f(n) is the count for n, and f(n, k) is the count for n of those substrings that end with k for k in {0,1,2}.

```
N  f(n, 0)  f(n, 1)  f(n, 2)  f(n)
0       0        0        0     0      
1       1        0        0     1      
2       1        2        0     3      
3       1        2        3     6      
4       5        2        3    10       
5       5        8        3    16       
6       5        8       12    25        
7      18        8       12    38        
8      18       27       12    57          
9      18       27       40    85          
10     59       27       40    126           
11     59       87       40    186
```

Methodology: f(n, k) only changes if the n'th string ends with k. In that case:

```
f(n, k) = f(n-1, k) + f(n-1, k') + 1
Where k' is the predecessor of k in '012' with wraparound.

E.g., f(6,2) = 12 = f(5,2) + f(5,1) + 1
```

The intuition here is that we have all the ways of ending with k that don't use the newest letter (f(n-1, k)), All the ways that do use the newest k, which must equal all the ways of using the prior letter in the sequence with this added k at the end (f(n-1, k')), together with the singleton new k (+1).

This is linear time, constant memory.

-- update -- If you read the numbers that change: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 18, 27, 40, 59, 87, 128, 188, 276, 405, 594, 871, this is [OEIS sequence A077868](https://oeis.org/A077868).

-- update --

```
[a, b, c, 1] * [0, 0, 1, 0] = [b, c, a+c+1, 1]
               [1, 0, 0, 0]
               [0, 1, 1, 0]
               [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Call the square matrix above M. Then we can use M to calculate successive values of k. E.g., [12, 18, 27, 1] * M = [18, 27, 40, 1]

We can use this to solve f(n) in log time by repeatedly squaring the matrix.

```
E.g. M^8 = [4,   6,  9, 0]
           [3,   4,  6, 0]
           [6,   9, 13, 0]
           [12, 18, 27, 1]

[0, 0, 0, 1] * M^8 = [12, 18, 27, 1]
12 + 18 + 27 = 57 = f(8)
```

f(n) is the sum of the first three elements of the bottom row of M^n.

So f(n) can be calculated in log time, though because matrix mult is fairly expensive this only makes sense for relatively large n. Note that this works for numbers that aren't powers of 2 by multiplying together the matrices of the appropriate powers of 2. E.g. 13 = 1101, so we multiply (M^1)*(M^4)*(M^8).

Comment: I wonder if a repeated matrix squaring approach could get this down to log time (similar to https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-calculate-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-logarithmic-time-abde842f5a39 for Fibonacci).